Cannot delete SQL column
I have this Java Spring project where I'm trying to make a CRUD of the SQL tables Concierto, Cancion and Artista. The table Concierto is not related to nothing so it works with deleteById(). For Cancion I had to create a method to delete all the columns related to the song in other columns first, and then deleting the Cancion. The problem is that for Artista I tried to make the same thing, deleting everything related to it and then deleting it. This is the code:
package com.ejemplos.models.entity;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Artista {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String nombre;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Descripcion
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="artista", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Descripcion descripcion;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "artista", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Album> albumes;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Cancion
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="artista", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Cancion> canciones;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "artista", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private ImgArtista imgArtista;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "artista", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<RrssArtista> rrssArtista;

    // Getters y Setters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Descripcion getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(Descripcion descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public List<Album> getAlbumes() {
        return albumes;
    }

    public void setAlbums(List<Album> albumes) {
        this.albumes = albumes;
    }

    public List<Cancion> getCanciones() {
        return canciones;
    }

    public void setCanciones(List<Cancion> canciones) {
        this.canciones = canciones;
    }

    public ImgArtista getImgArtista() {
        return imgArtista;
    }

    public void setImgArtista(ImgArtista imgArtista) {
        this.imgArtista = imgArtista;
    }

    public List<RrssArtista> getRrssArtista() {
        return rrssArtista;
    }

    public void setRrssArtistas(List<RrssArtista> rrssArtista) {
        this.rrssArtista = rrssArtista;
    }

    // Método toString
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Artista{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", nombre='" + nombre + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}


package com.ejemplos.models.entity;
import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Cancion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private Date fechaSalida;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_artista")
    private Artista artista;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_album")
    private Album album;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "cancion")
    private Portada portada;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cancion", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Enlace> enlaces;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cancion", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Valoracion> valoraciones;

    // Getters y Setters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Date getFechaSalida() {
        return fechaSalida;
    }

    public void setFechaSalida(Date fechaSalida) {
        this.fechaSalida = fechaSalida;
    }

    public Artista getArtista() {
        return artista;
    }

    public void setArtista(Artista artista) {
        this.artista = artista;
    }

    public Album getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(Album album) {
        this.album = album;
    }

    public Portada getPortada() {
        return portada;
    }

    public void setPortada(Portada portada) {
        this.portada = portada;
    }

    public List<Enlace> getEnlaces() {
        return enlaces;
    }

    public void setEnlaces(List<Enlace> enlaces) {
        this.enlaces = enlaces;
    }

    public List<Valoracion> getValoraciones() {
        return valoraciones;
    }

    public void setValoracion(List<Valoracion> valoraciones) {
        this.valoraciones = valoraciones;
    }

    // Método toString
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cancion{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", nombre='" + nombre + '\'' +
                ", fechaSalida=" + fechaSalida + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}


    @GetMapping("/borrar/{tipo}/{id}")
    public String borrar(@PathVariable("tipo") String tipo, @PathVariable("id") int id, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        UsuarioActivo usuarioActivo = getUsuarioActivo(request);
        if (usuarioActivo.getUsuario().getAdmin() == true) {
            switch (tipo) {
                case "artista":
                    borrarArtista(id);
                    break;
                case "cancion": 
                    borrarCancion(id);
                    break;
                case "concierto":
                    conciertoService.deleteById(id);
                    break;
            }
            return "redirect:/admin";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public void borrarArtista(int id) {
        Artista artista = artistaService.findById(id);
        if (artista != null) {
            Descripcion descripcion = artista.getDescripcion();
            List<Cancion> canciones = artista.getCanciones();
            ImgArtista imgArtista = artista.getImgArtista();
            List<RrssArtista> rrssArtista = artista.getRrssArtista();
            List<Album> albumes = artista.getAlbumes();

            if (descripcion != null) {
                descripcionService.deleteById(descripcion.getId());
            }
            if (imgArtista != null) {
                imgArtistaService.deleteById(imgArtista.getId());
            }
            if (rrssArtista != null) {
                for (RrssArtista rsArtista : rrssArtista) {
                    rrssArtistaService.deleteById(rsArtista.getId());
                }
            }
            if (canciones != null) {
                for (Cancion cancion : canciones) {
                    borrarCancion(cancion.getId());
                }
            }
            if (albumes != null) {
                for (Album album : albumes) {
                    for (Cancion cancion : album.getCanciones()) {
                        borrarCancion(cancion.getId());
                    }
                    albumService.deleteById(album.getId());
                }
            }
            artistaService.deleteById(id);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Artista con id " + id + " no encontrado.");
        }
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public void borrarCancion(int id) {
        Cancion cancion = cancionService.findById(id);
        if (cancion != null) {
            Portada portada = cancion.getPortada();
            List<Enlace> enlaces = cancion.getEnlaces();
            List<Valoracion> valoraciones = cancion.getValoraciones();

            if (portada != null) {
                portadaService.deleteById(portada.getId());
            }
            if (enlaces != null) {
                for (Enlace enlace : enlaces) {
                    enlaceService.deleteById(enlace.getId());
                }
            }
            if (valoraciones != null) {
                for (Valoracion valoracion : valoraciones) {
                    valoracionService.deleteById(valoracion.getId());
                }
            }

            cancionService.deleteById(id);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cancion con id " + id + " no encontrada.");
        }
    }

The error that pops up is related to the fact that the column "id_cancion" is declared as not null, so it has conflict at some point. This is the error:
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:296)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:533)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.ejemplos.models.service.ArtistaServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1634c350.deleteById(<generated>)
    at com.ejemplos.controllers.Controlador.borrarArtista(Controlador.java:341)
    at com.ejemplos.controllers.Controlador.borrar(Controlador.java:292)
    at com.ejemplos.controllers.Controlador$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$61ffa338.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684)
    at com.ejemplos.controllers.Controlador$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84cc854c.borrar(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3356)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3229)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3283)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2479)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:532)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id_cancion' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:970)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1109)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1057)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1377)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1042)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 86 more

Thank you very much in advance!
I tried adding the Transactional annotation and adding cascade to the classes, but it didn't work.

Rather than the hibernate definition, I'd look at the actual table definition. There seems to be a constraint to id_cancion that you are violating with your deletion strategy. Check which constraint and then adjust your deletion strategy. In addition, you might want to use a custom query to delete rather than go via the regular repository operations. You can do that within hibernate/springboot repositories with respective Annotations (though I'd recommend in general to just go and start using jOOQ).
If you have control over the table structure you can also simply define foreign key reference constraints with a CASCADE option to make sure dependent entries are deleted as soon as the referenced row is deleted.

How would that work? Also, this is my creation querys:
CREATE TABLE artista(
id int NOT NULL auto_increment UNIQUE,
nombre varchar(30),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE cancion(
id int NOT NULL auto_increment UNIQUE,
nombre varchar(60),
fecha_salida date,
id_artista int NOT NULL,
id_album int,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id_artista) REFERENCES artista(id),
FOREIGN KEY (id_album) REFERENCES album(id)
);
